# java is insecure message when running some applets

Tags: java, security, applet

I have Java 1.7 installed.  We have a web site with two applets.  When one of them is loaded I receive the following dialog.  When the other is loaded I don't.  Why is it that some applets cause this security warning and others don't?

Is there something in particular that causes this warning?

[image: security warning]

Dialog text in searchable form:
Do you want to run this application?  Your version of Java is insecure and an application from the location below is requesting permission to run.

Comment: *"others don't?"*  Links to examples?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure.  Perhaps it is because, although your question is slightly different to the others, this matter has been discussed a few times over the preceding days. To be honest, I was borderline between 'post a quick answer' and 'search for duplicates'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I discovered the cause of this warning.  This is apparently a new security feature of Java 7.  When you execute an applet a call is made home to Oracle to see if your Java is up to date.  If it is not up to date you receive this new dialog letting you know so.  The primary risk identified in the dialog is that there is a new patch for Java.  If you update Java you will no longer receive this dialog until the next update comes out.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something in particular that causes this warning?

Code that is not digitally signed.  See [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html) .

Comment: That might be it.  I know one is signed and I don't believe the other is.  I will look into this and report back.  Thanks